# Asserting each property is defined in a TypeScript Partial<> does not narrow the type to "whole" / "complete" - why?

Tags: typescript

A TypeScript compile error occurs despite asserting each property in a Partial<> is defined. Why?

[**TypeScript Playground Link**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.3.2#code/PTAEh4Nx1-ceD-QZQKIBUCqAFAUBglgOwC4CmATgGYCGAxoaGgPYDO+oA3hqKACblEBcoAER6EA3O1D5s+ADaF+TYngDmYgL5ZZzAA6N8-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)

```typescript
// ️ SETUP

interface Post {
  date: Date;
  title: string;
}

let post: Partial<Post> = {
  date: new Date(),
  title: 'hello stackoverflow' 
};

const posts: Post[] = [];

// ❌ THIS DOESN'T WORK:

if (post.date !== undefined && post.title !== undefined) { // why doesn't this enable the subsequent line?
  posts.push(post);
  //         ^^^^ Argument of type 'Partial<Post>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Post'.
  //                Types of property 'date' are incompatible.
  //                  Type 'Date | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Date'.
  //                    Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Date'.(2345)
}

// ✅ THIS WORKS:

function isPost(post: Partial<Post>): post is Post {
  return post.date !== undefined && post.title !== undefined;
}

if (isPost(post)) {
  posts.push(post);
}
```

Comment: See e.g. [microsoft/TypeScript#44866](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44866) and the various issues it links to.

Comment: Yes it does- thank you. I added a close-dup vote